# valhala larval objects need

Tags: java, project-valhalla

I'm watching a video, [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tWonozjIE-s&t=5940s) and Remi basically says that `value classes` must have their fields `final`. This makes sense, since they will need to be copied to methods, since they don't have references to be passed.

The thing he later says, I don't understand:

> final fields can be modified during the execution of a constructor.

and that is why they need to create so-called `larval` instances.

If an instance has all fields `final`, it is considered to be safely initialized. This is what Shipilev [says in this famous article](https://shipilev.net/blog/2014/safe-public-construction/):

> Safe initialization makes all values initialized in constructor visible to all readers that observed the object, regardless of whether the object was safely published or not

So that statement makes me really confused. Is there anything that the VM does different for value classes?

Comment: I'm not sure I've watched enough of that video, just a couple of minutes, but I don't think the JVM is doing anything different.  I think instead what Remi is proposing is relaxing the Java language syntax.  For convenience, in a constructor final fields would be allowed to be modified.  That's the "larval" stage of an object he's talking about.

Comment: @markspace yeah, you probably watched just too little, his point is kind of: the rules are a) fields must be final b) we need to protect ourselves _because_ "final fields can be modified inside a constructor"

Comment: How far should I watch?  All I saw was a new compiler warning for a "this escape."  That problem (the this-escape) isn't new and isn't caused by final fields or larval objects.  It's super old, they're just adding a warning (and eventually an error) for that problem.

Comment: @markspace even the this escape, at least from my understanding, is stil related to valhala. But anyway, at the exact time what I provided in the question, on that slide: "Problem with method calls" there are two bullets: one that fields must be final, and then there is that "But that's not enough" and he goes on about that "not enough" part related to final fields and constructor

Comment: The two points on that slide: "All fields must be declared `final`.  But that is not enough."  Remi then talks about larval objects.  To me they sound exactly like the way `final` fields and immutable objects work right now, and have worked since Java 1.5.  The differences sound largely conceptual, a mental model for the programmer.  He then says that the calling code is exactly the same, and that `this` escapes are also bad.  Exactly the same as now.  I don't know for certain, but this sounds at most to be a compiler change, maybe byte codes, but not the JVM.